# How can I use rsync to rewrite files in place?

Tags: rsync

I have a ZFS dataset that I want to enable compression on. Enabling the compression option is easy enough, but does not apply retroactively, only files written after enabling the option are compressed. Therefore, I am searching for a way to rewrite every file without having to copy them to another disk temporarily or similar.

In a [5 year old comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/6o3l28/comment/dkek8cl/), a reddit user claims

> I have actually used rsync to compress in place. With the correct command line options, it makes a temp file and over writes the original with the copy in place. The only downside is if you stop half way through it doesn't know where to resume.

What are the "correct command line options"?

Comment: What is the benefit in using rsync if there's no resume capability? Given the description you provided ("temp file") the operation is not done "in place".

Comment: Note that using rsync (or cp or any method that copies the files and then renames them over their original filename) will be written to entirely new set of blocks on the dataset.  If you have snapshots containing the old files, then both old and new files will take up space on the dataset until you delete the old snapshot(s).

Comment: Probably the best way to deal with this is to use `zfs send -R` to create a backup of the dataset either to another location in the same pool, a different pool (possibly on another system), or to a file (optionally compressed).   Then destroy the dataset and `zfs receive` it from the backup.   Worth noting: saving the backup to the same disk or pool as the original dataset will be **much** slower than saving the backup to anywhere else because of read & write contention, especially so if the dataset is on a HDD pool.

Comment: Also worth noting, you can't unmount or destroy a dataset while it's in use (e.g. some process has a file open on it, or you have executed a program with the cwd under that dataset, or a shell whose cwd is on that dataset).   IIRC, you can `zfs rename` the dataset rather than `zfs destroy` it if it's in use, which would allow you to `zfs receive` it...then destroy the renamed dataset some other time when it's no longer in use.

Comment: nope, i just tested and you can't rename a dataset if it's in use.

Comment: @cas You can, but you have to ensure that the mountpoint property doesn't change, which is often the case when things are left to their defaults. And all the caveats you mentioned above re: open files, active CWDs, etc. Also, my test was with a manual mount, ala `mount -t zfs pool/fs /mnt`.

Comment: renaming it wouldn't have been practical, anyway. i shouldn't have even suggested it.  the point is to restore the backup to the same dataset name with the same mount-point.  and if the original ds was in use during the initial backup then an incremental zfs send would have to be done after it was no longer in use to keep the new ds in sync with any changes. more trouble than it's worth,  best to quit out of (or just kill) any process using the ds while the backup & restore is being done.